# pass associative array in input field in form PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I want to know the best and easiest way to pass associative array in form inside input field. So far Ive done this and it all started to look messy and hard to handle.

```
$dish_result = $obj->getAll_dish();// this returns array all the rows in dish table
<form action='order_process.php' method='post'>
   foreach ($dish_result as $dish){
     echo '<input id="" name="dish_name[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $dish['dish_name'].'">';
     echo '<input id="" name="dish_number[]" type="checkbox" value="'. $dish['dish_number'].'">';         
     }
</form>
```

Now on the order_process.php I have

```
 foreach($_POST['dish_name'] as $dish){
        echo $dish;
  }
 foreach($_POST['dish_number'] as $num){
       echo $num;
 }
```

What I wanted is an associative array, but how can I associate it the form dynamically. in other words I wanted to achieve this on the order_process.php.

```
 $dishes = array(
       //'dish_name' => dish_number
      'chickencurry' => '70',
      'onionbhajis'  =>  '22'
       // and so on. 
  );
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What happens if you change your foreach to include `$key => $dish` and set the inputs as `name="dish_name[{$key}]"`.. ? That way you could map the values to their keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grouping name first, then to get that kind of structure, make the dish name as key, then the value attribute holds the number. The basic idea is this:

```
name="dish[dishname]" value="dish_number"
```

It'll be like this:

```
echo '<input id="" name="dish['.$dish['dish_name'].']" type="checkbox" value="'. $dish['dish_number'].'" />';
```

When you submit it with all the checkbox checked, it should be something like:

```
Array
(
    [chickencurry] => 1
    [onionbhajis] => 2
)
```

On the `order_process.php` page, just call it just like you normally do:

```
$dishes = $_POST['dish'];
foreach($dishes as $dish_name => $dish_number) {

}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DCvZrx)

Comment: Thank you Sir. What an elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an index to array postdata. Try this:

```php
  foreach ($dish_result as $dish){
      echo '<input id="" name="dishes['.$dish['dish_name'].']" type="checkbox" value="'. $dish['dish_number'].'">'; 
  }
```

Your data will then be an associative array of the checked elements when posted back.